# Error al obtener propiedades de un objeto

Tags: php, poo

Estoy empezando en el mundo de la POO con PHP. Al acceder a las propiedades del objeto `Persona` mediante un getter no me aparece su valor correspondiente.

El código de la clase es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    class Persona{
        public $nombre;
        public $apellido;
        public $dni;

        function setName($nombre){
            $this -> nombre = $nombre;
        }
        function getName(){
            return $this -> nombre;
        }
    }
?>
```

Seguidamente en otro `archivo.php` creo un objeto de esa clase y le doy unos valores:

```
<?php
    require_once("class.php"); // fichero de la clase anterior
    $marcos = new Persona();
    $marcos -> setName('Marcos');
    $marcos -> getName();
?>
```

Si accedo a este script en mi navegador no me aparece absolutamente nada. Pero si modifico el código y lo presento de la siguiente forma sí que me muestra por pantalla **Marcos**.

```
<?php 

    require_once("class.php");
    $marcos = new Persona();
    $marcos -> setName('Marcos');

?>

<?= 

    $marcos -> getName();

?>
```

¿Cómo es esto? ¿Qué diferencia hay entre `<?php ?>` y `<?= ?>`?

Comment: La programación POO en PHP puede convertirse en algo _irreal_ en el estricto sentido de la palabra, y ello debido en gran parte a la mala calidad de los ejemplos sobre el tema, incluso en el mismo Manual de PHP. Uno de los fundamentos de la POO es el _encapsulamiento_, el cual debe ser aplicado _también_ en el caso de los `getters` y de los `setters`. Un objeto cuyo `setter` sea **público** viola gravemente el principio fundamental antes mencionado. Si los `setters` son públicos no podemos entonces hablar de POO en el sentido estricto de la palabra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ¿Qué diferencia hay entre `<?php ?>` y `<?= ?>`?

Las etiquetas tienen el siguiente propósito:

- `<?php ... ?>`: delimitar un bloque de código PHP.
- `<?= ... ?>`: equivalente a `<?php echo ...; ?>`.

Puedes ver su significado y ejemplos de uso en [la documentación de PHP](http://php.net/basic-syntax.phpmode#example-84):

> 2. Puede emplear la etiqueta `echo` abreviada para `<?= 'imprimir esta cadena' ?>`.
>      Siempre está habilitada en PHP 5.4.0 y posterior, y es equivalente a
>      `<?php echo 'imprimir esta cadena' ?>`.

## Solución

Para que te funcione tu código debes usar `echo` para enviar el valor al navegador:

```
<?php
require_once("class.php"); // fichero de la clase anterior
$marcos = new Persona();
$marcos -> setName('Marcos');
/* Enviar al navegador el contenido */
echo $marcos -> getName();
/* Mejor aún */
echo htmlspecialchars($marcos->getName());
```

Es lo que hacías de manera implícita al usar la etiqueta `<?= ... ?>`.